# How to fix the error Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Please help me with this error
Errors

```
Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;

Error:Execution failed for task ':SchedulerApp:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: check your module dependency.. maybe it duplicate in other modules..

Comment: add you project root .gradle as well\

Answer (score 2):

1. Try `clean` and then `Make Project`
2. Add `multiDexEnabled = true` in DefaultConfig.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Error:(7, 0) Could not set unknown property 'multiDexEnabled' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\nbuzo\Desktop\App\SchedulerApp\build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: Hi Nikolai i am getting same error please let me know if any solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try changing,

```
compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')
```

with

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a multidex issue.

**You are adding the same class** (Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl) **twice**.
This class is in you project `android-support-v7-appcompat` and inside the dependency of firebase.

Why are you using this?

`compile project(':android-support-v7-appcompat')`

I suggest you using instead

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:XX.X.X'
```